# iOS accelerometer and GPS

Tags: ios, gps, accelerometer

have a question about developing iOS app.
Is it possible to use accelerometer and GPS at the same time?
Example: we want to run app only when iphone is moving and check with accelerometer when it suddenly stops and call some actions...

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Core Location and Core Motion fame works at the same time